# Serializeable In-Memory Full-Text Index Tool for Ruby

Tags: ruby, serialization, indexing, full-text-search

I am trying to find a way to build a full-text index stored in-memory in a format that can be safely passed through `Marshal.dump`/`Marshal.load` so I can take the index and encrypt it before storing it to disk.

My rationale for needing this functionality: I am designing a system where a user's content needs to be both encrypted using their own key, and indexed for full text searching. I realize there would be significant overhead and memory usage if for each user of the system I had to un-marshal and load the entire index of their content into memory. For this project security is far more important than efficiency.

A full text index would maintain far too many details about a user's content to leave unencrypted, and simply storing the index on an encrypted volume is insufficient as each user's index would need to be encrypted using the unique key for that user to maintain the level of security desired.

User content will be encrypted and likely stored in a traditional RDBMS. My thought is that loading/unloading the serialized index would be less overhead for a user with large amounts of content than decrypting all the DB rows belonging to them and doing a full scan for every search.

My trials with `ferret` got me to the point of successfully creating an in-memory index. However, the index failed a `Marshal.dump` due to the use of `Mutex`. I am also evaluating `xapian` and `solr` but seem to be hitting roadblocks there as well.

Before I go any further I would like to know if this approach is even a sane one and what alternatives I might want to consider if its not. I also want to know if anyone has had any success with serializing a full-text index in this manner, what tool you used, and any pointers you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a standard full-text search engine and keep each client's index on a separate encrypted disk image, like TrueCrypt? Each client's disk image could have a unique key, it would use less RAM, and would probably take less time to implement.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I will look at TrueCrypt and if there are no better answers I'll accept yours and go that route. Thanks.

Comment: Decided to use `encfs` instead since the app will be hosted on Ubuntu and `encfs` is even easier to set up than TrueCrypt. Same idea though. Your answer definitely set me on the right path.